# How to Unit Test A Method Argument which is a Builder Class in Mockito?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have a dependency in the Spring Boot which is called from my class. This dependency makes a call with a newly instantiated builder pattern class as an argument. I need to know if it is possible to verify if this single builder class was constructed with certain values when the dependency call is made, e.g.:

```
public class MyClass {

  @Autowired
  private MyDep myDep;

  public void callMyDepService() {
    myDep.serviceCall(new MyBuilder().paramOne("One").paramTwo("Two").build());
  }

}
```

As you can see, a new `MyBuilder` is instantiated every time, so I can't just use Mockito's `eq()` to match the arguments' value.

Comment: What class does `MyBuilder` build? You can use that and define it for `any()` (or just use any without defining a class), If you want to validate your argument use a `Captor` or use `thenAnswer` / `doAnswer` to intercept the parameter.

Comment: Besides that you should have a seperate test for the `MyBuilder` class that verifies that it builds correctly. If your `myDep.serviceCall` requires certain properties the class itself should validate this, which again would be a seperate test.

Comment: @second I would like to make sure `callMyDepService` calls `myDep.serviceCall` with certain parameter values. They are hard coded, and there are several of these `callMyDepService` methods with similar dependency service calls. I am not concern about the builder class as it has its own unit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to make sure callMyDepService calls myDep.serviceCall with certain parameter values.

Using a captor seems to be the easiest way to do that.
Something like this, where `SomeClass` is the class your `MyBuilder` builds.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class CaptureTest {

    @InjectMocks
    MyClass classUnderTest;

    @Mock
    MyDep myDep;

    @Test
    public void test() {

        classUnderTest.callMyDepService();

        Captor<SomeClass> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(SomeClass.class);
        Mockito.verify(myDep).serviceCall(captor.capture());

        SomeClass parameter = captor.getValue();
        // do assertions
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually went out and read on `Captor` and got it working. It seems like `@Captor` is a more preferable approach.

Comment: I would say it depends on whether you reuse the Captor over different tests or not. If your have multiple tests and everyone uses a different captors, having them all defined on top is less readable (as you need to figure out which test is using what exactly). But thats based on my opinion.

Comment: Yes, in the scenario u described, you are right. However, as I mentioned, my tests will eventually call on this dependency service with an identical builder class, so it makes sense to declare a single `ArgumentCaptor` and reuse it in every test.

Comment: What if i pass MyBuilder.Build() as argument? How do you configure the captor in this case? I tried Mockito.verify(myDep).serviceCall(captor.capture().build()); but obviously it will return null.